# mb_ereg_search_init working as single-byte?

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring

Check this snippet:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_ereg_search_init('καλημέραCCC', 'C+');
$pos = mb_ereg_search_pos();
echo $pos[0];
```

(Please don't comment on this specific example, it's not my use case, it's a reduction of the problem I'm having)

Even though the string "καλημέρα" consists of 8 characters, the snippet above prints 16.
Am I missing something? Isn't mb_ereg_search_init supposed to support multi-byte?
And if I am, is there any built-in function that does what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't a normal `preg_match` with `u` modifier work?

Comment: preg_match returns the number of matches (0 or 1, since it stops at first match), not the position of the match in the string :/

Comment: I'm conjecturing, but `mb_internal_encoding()` might be set to UCS2, so `_pos()` returns the actual byte offset(?)

Comment: And you could still use `preg_match` with [`$flags=PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - though it's not as nice an API.

Comment: No, it's not the internal encoding (snippet updated). I'll try preg_match with that flag, thanks!

Comment: No, the offset captured by preg_match is in bytes, even with the u modifier. :(

Answer (score 0):

From manual page for [`mb_ereg_search_pos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-search-pos.php):

> An array including the position of a matched part for a multibyte
>   regular expression. The first element of the array will be the
>   beginning of matched part, the second element will be length (**bytes**)
>   of matched part. It returns FALSE on error.

My interpretation is that it's always returning number of bytes, not the actual position. If you check more of these multi-byte functions, there is at least [one more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-search-getpos.php) that hints that it's supposed to work this way. Don't ask me what's the purpose of this function then...

If you want to know just position of first `C`, you can use [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php):

```
mb_strpos('καλημέραCCC', 'C'); // 8
```

If you want to simply hack it at all costs, there's a solution. You have to decode the string first:

```
mb_ereg_search_init(utf8_decode('καλημέραCCC'), 'C+');
```

String becomes `????????CCC`, each of question marks is exactly 1 byte and you are able to count them properly. However, if you wanna use multi-byte character in regexp now (`'λ+'`), it won't work.